# create "generic" structures in c++

Tags: c++, struct, generic-type-argument

I want to create a structure within a structure that is defined at runtime, with variables that I can reference in the parent structure's functions. Basically, this:

```
struct Bar
{
  int val = 0;
}
struct Foo
{
  struct *generic_struct;
  Foo()
  {
    generic_struct = Bar;
    generic_struct.val++;
  }
}
int main()
{
  Foo foo;
}
```

I know that that's not what pointers do, but I don't have a better way to describe what I expect. I also from my limited understanding of C++ realize that there is probably no way to do what I want, but what would be the best closest thing?

Comment: You want to be looking at _templates_: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates

Comment: If you want it to be anything then there is `std::any`.  If you want to limit the types then you could  use `std::variant`.

Comment: @JMAA templates are compile time only.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, but they're idiomatic for generic programming in C++ and if it can be done at compile-time, it's generally better to

Comment: depending on what you want to do with that struct, `std::variant` or a pointer to an abstract class

Comment: You can use templates. Please see the code here:- https://pastebin.com/x4LZBdjT

Comment: you need to better explain what you want to do. For one, there is nothing "at runtime" in your example

Comment: @user463035818 I want to define a struct variable within a struct, that I can, at runtime, turn into a specific struct type. Basically, so that an instance of it is generated within the parent structure. In my example that happens in the Foo constructor - that is called at runtime.

Comment: hm actually it is in particular this what i dont understand. If you know in `Foo`s constructor what type the struct should be then there is no need to defer the declaration of the member type to runtime. I mean you write the constructor before runtime so you also know already that the member should be a `Bar`

Comment: @ user463035818 I put the declaration in the constructor for the sake of simplicity, but that's not the only place I need it in.  To sum it up, I want to be able to turn generic_struct into a random struct at runtime, and then access that struct's variables. So, for example, I need to be able to write
'
Foo foo;
foo.generic_struct = Bar;
foo.generic_struct.val++;
'

Comment: @sonulohani I don't think I can. From what I understand, if generic_struct is a template, then once it is declared to be one type at compile, it is that type forever. I need to be able to change it at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a few options:

I. Use inheritance.

```
struct Struct {
    virtual Struct &setVal(int) = 0;
    virtual ~Struct() {}
};
struct Bar: Struct {
    int val = 0;
    Struct &setVal(int that) { val = that; return *this; }х
};
struct Foo {
    std::unique_ptr<Struct> str;
    Foo(): str(std::make_unique<Bar>()) {}
};
```

II. (Somewhat Pythonic/javascripty.) Use maps. This way they are really runtime provided you know the set of *all the possible* types struct's fields can belong to.

```
template<typename... types> using Struct
     = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::variant<types...>>;
auto bar() { return Struct<int, char, double>{{"val", 0}}; }

struct Foo {
     Struct<int, char, double> generic_struct;
     Foo(): generic_struct(bar()) {
         ++std::get<int>(generic_struct["val"]);
     }
};
```

III. Make `Foo` templated, if you can.

```
template<typename Struct> struct Foo {
     Struct generic_struct;
     Foo() { ++generic_struct.val; }
};
```

(Add some SFINAE to make all the struct accesses compile.)

Others are probably even more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to define a new struct at runtime with members that may not be known at compile time, and still be able to reference the members and functions of the newly created struct. I was looking into similar functionality so that in the application I was working on, the end user could create new custom classes at runtime and the system would allow them to be used like any other included/compiled class. Also, I was working in C# at the time, not C++.

The system I had to learn to create that functionality is pretty complicated and I haven't used the C++ implementation. In C# you would use the Reflection namespace. C++ has an open source library called Run Time Type Reflection (RTTR), which is still considered "Experimental", that you may want to look into. Like I said though, complicated, and I really can't claim to know anything about the C++ library.

If that sounds like what you are looking for, here is the link to the RTTR homepage:

[Run Time Type Reflection Library Home Page](https://www.rttr.org/).

---

I believe this is a separate, unrelated solution but on CppReference.com there is documentation for a 'Reflection Technical Specification' that "specifies modifications to the core language and defines new components for the C++ standard library listed on this page." So it seems to be an extension of the standard library instead of a separate library.

Here are some examples, [Reflection TS: reflexpr keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/reflexpr), and the definition of the extension, [Standard Library Reflection Extensions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/reflect).